# How to read image files from the gallery of the phone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have a problem with this code, in practice i'm trying to read from the gallery of the phone only the file name image2.jpg image3.jpg ... etc.
but this code gives me error

this is the Code:

```
 public static Uri getRandomImage(ContentResolver resolver) {

    String secondo = "image2.jpg";
    String terzo = "image3.jpg";
    String quarto = "image4.jpg";
    String quinto = "image5.jpg";
    String sesto = "image6.jpg";
    String settimo = "image7.jpg";
    String ottavo = "image8.jpg";

    String[] projection = new String[] {
        BaseColumns._ID,
        MediaColumns.DATA,

    };



    Uri uri = Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cursor =  Media.query(resolver, uri, projection, null, MediaColumns._ID);
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            return null;
    }

    cursor.moveToPosition(new Random().nextInt(cursor.getCount()));

    String completefilepath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA));
    if(completefilepath == secondo || completefilepath == terzo || completefilepath == quarto ||
            completefilepath == quinto || completefilepath == sesto || completefilepath == settimo ||
            completefilepath == ottavo){

        string = cursor.getString(1);

    }
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, string);
}
```

this is the LOGCAT:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(9147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(9147): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown URL: content://media/external/images/media/null
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1268)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:538)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:467)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:380)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView.getImageFromUri(TileView.java:559)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView.newGame(TileView.java:156)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.SlidePuzzleActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(SlidePuzzleActivity.java:377)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2762)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8819)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:603)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(9147):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please,upload the error log as well.

Comment: edited my post with code and logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, int requestCode);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand how to use this your advice, could be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this and make changes as you want!!

XML::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

CLASS FILE ::

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageGalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {


    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't completely distort my code. All I need to be able to fix  method code getRandomImage to read the files from the folder created by me in which I copied those image files. The path to this folder is: / sdcard / DCIM / Wallpaper /